# PHP check and replace empty value before insert to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I need to check empty data value before insert into database. i have two way:

One:

```
$comment = (empty($_POST['regcomment'])) ? '0' : $_POST['regcomment'];

$sql = update("UPDATE " . OPTIONS . " SET comment = ? ", $comment);
```

Two :

```
$sql = update("UPDATE " . OPTIONS . " SET comment = ? ", (empty($_POST['regcomment'])) ? '0' : $_POST['regcomment']);
```

which way is better?!

Comment: Please check your code to make sure you copied correctly.

Comment: The first - it's much more readable. Side note you don't need brackets around the `empty()`

Comment: @Novocaine, both are broken. I think he forgot to close the string when he copied here.

Comment: I suggest you to use first option in correct manner and as per your options. You will never get data in your table

Comment: @AlexLinte: add `"` and this true.

Comment: You can as well use a `CASE` condition.

Comment: o-O: Have you ever heard about SQL injection? Use prepared statements or at least escape your DB input!

Comment: @lxg: LOL! i prevent and sanitize all $_POST before insert :) and my database method is likely PDO ;)

Comment: Ok, then sorry. At first sight, your code looked like a custom query builder that just concatenates some parameters. (Because we have dozens of them every day, and I'm pulling my hair each time when imagining the amounts of vulnerable web apps that must be out there in the wild.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is primarily opinion based. It both leads to the same result, the only difference is that in the second version you do not have the result of the ternary-statement in a variable in case you need it again.

In the first version the ternary-statement and function-call are split, so it's arguably more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The first option is preferable though, both options do the same thing.

The first one is readable, this is the only thing.